# Store data after decompression in pig

Tags: tuples, apache-pig

Format of my file is -

```
 ({"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3})
    ({"food":"Tomato Soup", "person":"Sarah", "amount":2})
    ({"food":"Grilled Cheese", "person":"Alex", "amount":5})
```

I tried to store this using the following code

```
STORE STOCK_A 
    INTO 'default.ash_json_pigtest' 
    USING HCatStorer();
```

Stored data as shown below.

```
 {"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3}             None    None
    {"food":"Tomato Soup", "person":"Sarah", "amount":2}    None    None
    {"food":"Grilled Cheese", "person":"Alex", "amount":5}  None    None
```

Expected out put is

```
    Tacos           Alice   3
    Tomato Soup     Sarah   2
    Grilled Cheese  Alex    5
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does a DESCRIBE on STOCK_A say?

Comment: STOCK_A: {food: chararray,person: chararray,amount: int}

Comment: How are you reading the data? Because right now you are importing each row as an only chararray, not parsing your data... That is why you are getting that output.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not how you store the data, but how you are loading it. You have a JSON file but you are reading the whole JSON into one field, so you get only one field per row. When you save it into your HCatalog table, you get 1 row with the JSON in one field and two null fields.

Instead of loading the data with `PigStorage` or whatever you are using, load it with `JsonLoader`:

```
STOCK_TABLE = LOAD 'your.data' USING JsonLoader('food:chararray, person:chararray, amount:int');
```

You can `DUMP` the data to check that now it's correct:

```
DUMP STOCK_A;

(Tacos,Alice,3)
(Tomato Soup,Sarah,2)
(Grilled Cheese,Alex,5)
```

Instead of:

```
DUMP STOCK_A;

({"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3})
({"food":"Tomato Soup", "person":"Sarah", "amount":2})
({"food":"Grilled Cheese", "person":"Alex", "amount":5})
```

Comment: The above code will not work for my content.                                           ({"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3})...                  This will work, if my file content is -                                             {"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3}

Comment: Well, I don't think you can parse a Json inside a tuple unless you write your own UDF. It would be better for you to remove the parenthesis outside of Pig and then read it using `JsonLoader`. Anyway, if you are using the data from [this tutorial](http://joshualande.com/read-write-json-apache-pig/), you shouldn't have those parenthesis.