# Add data to hcatalog table using Pig

Tags: apache-pig, hcatalog

I have a JSON file with encoded data. My aim is to decode the data and save it to a HCat table with a schema (food,person,amount).

**myfile.json**

```
{"messages":[{"body":"eyJmb29kIjoiTWFuZ28iLCAicGVyc29uIjoiQWxpY2UiLCAiYW1vdW50IjoxMX0="}]}
{"messages":[{"body":"eyJmb29kIjoiQXBwbGUiLCAicGVyc29uIjoiVG9tIiwgImFtb3VudCI6MjJ9"}]}
{"messages":[{"body":"eyJmb29kIjoiT3JhbmdlIiwgInBlcnNvbiI6IkpvaG4iLCAiYW1vdW50IjozM30="}]}
```

**my code**

```
STOCK_A = LOAD 'myfile.json' 
USING JsonLoader('messages:{(body:chararray)}');    
rowarr1 = FOREACH STOCK_A GENERATE FLATTEN(messages.(body)) as (body);
decodearr = FOREACH rowarr1 GENERATE Base64Decode(body) as (msg);
DESCRIBE decodearr;        
DUMP decodearr;
```

**output**

```
decodearr: {msg: chararray}
({"food":"Mango", "person":"Alice", "amount":11})
({"food":"Apple", "person":"Tom", "amount":22})
({"food":"Orange", "person":"John", "amount":33})
```

How is it possible to split and save this with a schema of 
*{food: chararray,person: chararray,amount: int}*

Comment: I already answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476798/store-data-after-decompression-in-pig

Comment: --JsonLoader('food:chararray, person:chararray, amount:int')-- It will not work.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the contents of `myfile.json`? Not a `DUMP` inside Pig, but a `cat` outside of it.

Comment: {"messages":[{"body":"eyJmb29kIjoiTWFuZ28iLCAicGVyc29uIjoiQWxpY2UiLCAiYW1vdW50IjoxMX0="}]}
{"messages":[{"body":"eyJmb29kIjoiQXBwbGUiLCAicGVyc29uIjoiVG9tIiwgImFtb3VudCI6MjJ9"}]}
{"messages":[{"body":"eyJmb29kIjoiT3JhbmdlIiwgInBlcnNvbiI6IkpvaG4iLCAiYW1vdW50IjozM30="}]}

Comment: Well, unfortunately there is no builtin UDF that extracts JSON apart from the loader... So you have two options: [write a UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html#eval-functions) of your own to do so, or you could store the data after decoding it, and read it with `JsonLoader`... The latter is a simpler option but it's a quick and dirty solution.